# Show that the union and the finite intersection of open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ are open in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $z_1, z_2\in \mathbb{C}$ and let $r_1, r_2$ be positive real numbers.

I have shown that for all $z\in B(z_1, r_1)\cap B(z_2, r_2)$ there exists a $r>0$ such that \begin{equation*}B(z,r)\subseteq B(z_1, r_1)\cap B(z_2, r_2)\end{equation*}

I want to show, using the above, that the union and the finite intersection of open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ are open in $\mathbb{C}$.

$$$$

Do we show that as follows?

As for the union:

Let $U = \{U_i|i \in I\}$ be any collection of open sets of $\mathbb{C}$ and let $U = \cup_{i\in I} U_i$.

Let $x \in U$. Then $x \in U_i$ for some $i \in I$.

Since $U_i$ is open, there is $r > 0$ such that $B(x,r) \subset U_i$.

Therefore $B(x,r) \subset U$ and so $x$ is an interior point of $U$.

Since $x$ is arbitrary, every point of $U$ is an interior point of $U$ and so
$U$ is open.

As for the intersection:

Let $U = \{U_i|1\leq i\leq k\}$ be any collection of open sets of $\mathbb{C}$ and let $U = \cap_{i=1}^k U_i$.

Let $x\in U$. From the given proposition it follows that $B(x,r)\subseteq \cap_{i=1}^k U_i$.

$$$$

Is everything correct? Can we use the last line if we have previously showes by induction that it holds also for more than $2$?

Comment: This is true for arbitrary topological spaces; there is nothing special about $\mathbb C$ here. In fact this is the definition of a topological space - that open sets are closed under arbitrary unions and finite intersections.

Comment: Even then you can restate the question as: let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Show that $\mathcal{T}:= \{A \subseteq X\mid \forall a \in A: \exists \epsilon>0: B_d(a, \epsilon) \subseteq A\}$ is a topology.

Comment: @Math1000:  Your observation is correct, but the problem posed here is to use the *metric balls* in $\mathbb C$ to prove that "open sets" have the required properties regarding unions and finite intersections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is perfect. Not saying that (2) is wrong, but I think it is clearer to prove (2) directly:

Let $\{U_1, \dots, U_k\}$ be a finite collection of open sets. Take a point $x \in  \bigcap_{j=1}^k U_j.$ Thus $x$ is an interior point of $U_j$ for all $j\in \{1, \dots, k\}$, which means that we can find numbers $\epsilon_1 , \dots, \epsilon_k > 0$ such that

$$B(x, \epsilon_j) \subseteq U_j, \quad j = 1, 2, \dots, k$$

Now, define $\epsilon:= \min\{\epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_k\}>0$. Then

$$B(x,\epsilon) \subseteq \bigcap_{j=1}^kB(x,\epsilon_j) \subseteq \bigcap_{j=1}^k U_j$$
and we conclude that $x$ is an interior point of $\bigcap_{j=1}^k U_j$. This proves that this set is open. $\quad \square$

---

**Useful notes**:

(1) This proof crucually depends on the fact that the intersection is finite. Can you see where it breaks down if I allow infinite intersections?

(2) This proof generalises to arbitrary metric spaces. We did not use anything about $\mathbb{C}!$

(3) The properties you proved are very important. The entire mathematical discipline called topology is based on these properties!

Comment: I got it!! Thank you!! :-)